# How to move a SQL Agent Job to another Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, sql-server-agent

I'm moving from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008R2, and I see there is one job in the SQL Server Agent Jobs that I need to move but I see it also in the SSIS---> Stored Packages\MSDB\File Manipulation.
Not sure if I right click on it and choose export, would that affect the production server if it wont be working in the new dev server? or how I can import just a copy of it to the other new development SQL server 2008?

Thanks for any advice or direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you must be carefull when scripting out jobs. Especially jobs related to replciation.

Plus there is also sp_add_jobschedule and you need to decide that you want it in same shape on both servers. If yes you can re-create it but don;t use same @schedule_uid=N''

Comment: From https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/how-to-copy-sql-server-agent-jobs-between-servers/: "a word of warning, in my instance a lot of variables were still pointing at the old server, file directories and connections."

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about moving SQL Server Agent Job, I suggest you use the option "Script Job as -> Create" and than copy and paste the code on the new server. Once you have the code on the new server you can edit it (or execute it and than edit the job through Job Properties window) so it could work in a new enviroment.

Answer (score 4):

In SSMS, go to SQL Server Agent
Click on Jobs

Now Click on View->Object Explorer Details

You will have a list of all jobs on your right window. This way you can select multiple jobs that you want to script, right click and select "Script Job As" and then the options that you want.